# Disqus 2012 Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, disqus

Does anyone know how to style the new **Disqus 2012** plugin? I believe it is pulled onto your website via an **iFrame**. I want to know if you can target specific classes via jQuery and change the properties after that.

You may view an example here: http://www.iamaaron.com/beta-five/consistent.html

I cannot target any of the **Disqus** elements through jQuery... Am I doing this wrong? Here's is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery("#disqus-thread .publisher-anchor-color a").css({color:"#36B1BF"});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. All you can do is provide basic css and it'll take on that. If you change your `a` to something it'll interpret that. I've done some hackery to hide the buttons up top for example using a negative value for `margin-top`. You can't change anything through jQuery though because it's an iFrame not on your server. I know it's not the answer you were looking for but it's the answer.

Search this page for "css" and you'll see what I mean.

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768-introducing-disqus-2012-and-f-a-q-

Comment: Thanks Simon, I really appreciate the feedback. I did see this article... But I was hoping by some crazy instance that I should select something, somehow, and chance its appearance... But thank you!